# Creating a small page that generates 3 random words from 3 seperate lists at the click of a button

Tags: java, html, list, random

I coded a little in college but forget basically everything.  I want to create a bare bones page that has a button labeled "Generate" That will give you a 3 word sentence from 3 separate lists...basically :

list one has "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9"
list two has "a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i"
list three has "car, horse, gym, fair, boat"

You press "generate" and it puts three of those values into one sentence...
example : 4 h boat    after pressing generate...how can I do this?

Comment: Google "javascript select random element from list" and "javascript concatenate strings".

Comment: What @Jashaszun said, but use "Java", not "JavaScript".

Comment: @saadq That's what I meant, oops. I just saw "java" and "page" and my mind said "javascript webpage". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
Array.prototype.randomElement = function () {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)]
}
var list1 = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
var list2 = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];
var list3 = [ "car", "horse", "gym", "fair", "boat"];

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list1.randomElement() + " " 
    + list2.randomElement() + " " + list3.randomElement();
}
</script>
<p><p id="demo"></p></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad to help you, so please accept the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work